# For $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2+2020}$ find $x\in \mathbb{R} $ such that $ \int_0^x 2020 ^ {f^2(t)} dt = x$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

For $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2+2020}$ find $x\in \mathbb{R} $ such that $\displaystyle \int_0^x 2020 ^ {f^2(t)} dt = x$

Consider the function:

$$ f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + 2020}  $$

with $x \in \mathbb{R} $. I have to find $x$ such that the following is true:

$$ \int_0^x 2020 ^ {f^2(t)} dt = x $$

I tried defining the function:

$$ g(x) = 2020 ^ {f^2(x)} $$

with $x \in \mathbb{R} $. Then the equation that I have to solve would be:

$$ \int_0^x g(t) dt = x$$

And if we differentiate both sides we get:

$$g(x) = 1$$

$$ 2020 ^  {f^2(x)} = 2020^0$$

That means we have

$$ f^2(x) = 0 $$

$$ x^2 + 2020 =  0$$

$$ x^2 = - 2020$$

And I have no solutions in $\mathbb{R} $. What did I do wrong? I can see that $0$ would be a solution to the initial equation, so I must've done something wrong.

Comment: Is $f^2(x)$the second derivative of $f(x)$ or simply ${\left(f(x)\right)}^2$?

Comment: Do you mean $$\int_{a}^t2020^{x^2+2020}dx=x$$?

Comment: @Ty. It's the square of the function, so $(f(x)) ^2$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Well I double-checked and the exercise has only $x$'s in it, there are no other variables like $a$ or $t$. But I guess you're right and there should be $dt$ and $f^2(t)$ instead. I will edit the question.

Comment: what about $x=0$?

Comment: Q: Where did you encounter this question?  I wonder why they do and undo the square root for no apparent reason.

Comment: @LinAlg Well I can see that $x=0$ would be a solution since then we would have an integral with the same upper and lower bound, namely $0$, but the way I solved it says that there aren't any real solutions. That's what I am confused about. Besides, I found $x=0$ to be a solution merely by guessing, and that feels a bit odd, especially in mathematics :)

Comment: @BrianTung My teacher created it on the spot.

Comment: It looks a little impromptu, like a contest problem gone a bit haywire.  I don't think this can be solved in elementary functions.

Comment: Please avoid `\displaystyle` in titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to find $x$ such that
$$
\int _0^x 2020^{t^2+2020}\,dt = x
$$Clearly $x=0$ is a solution. There are no positive solutions, for we have
$$
\int _0^x 2020^{t^2+2020}\,dt-x =\int _0^x (2020^{t^2+2020}-1)\,dt >0
$$Now suppose $x<0$; let $y=-x>0$:
$$
\int _0^x 2020^{t^2+2020}\,dt-x = \int _0^{-y} 2020^{t^2+2020}\,dt+y
$$
$$
 = -\int _0^{y} 2020^{t^2+2020}\,dt+y = - \int _0^{y} (2020^{t^2+2020}-1)\,dt<0
$$So $x=0$ is the only solution.